# Boostrap 2.0: Adding a login form to a submenu, preventing close on focus

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 2.0 to build a navbar, pretty similar to the example on their site. I have a submenu (.dropdown-menu) in which I've placed a login-form (username, password, submit).

Everything renders just fine, but when I click the input fields for username or password the menu seems to think I clicked a menu item and the submenu is closed. Any hints on how I can prevent this?

Solution:

```
$('.dropdown form').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
})
```

Comment: D'oh! I tried `.preventDefault()` first and that didn't work. Glad this was simple, thanks for posting the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Add `persist` class for LI element.

// edit

JS code to make it actually work:

```
(function($) {
var toggle = '[data-toggle="dropdown"]';

function clearMenus() {
    var toggleParent = $(toggle).parent();
    if(!toggleParent.hasClass('persist'))
        toggleParent.removeClass('open');
}

$(function () {
    $('html').off('click.dropdown.data-api');
    $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus);
});
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: That does not seem to work. Maybe that was a feature in Bootstrap 1.x? There is no mention of "persist" in the CSS / JS files for 2.0.

Comment: yes, my bad, tho I didn't found solution for this problem that's why we made this function to accomplish this: `(function($) {
 var toggle = '[data-toggle="dropdown"]';

 function clearMenus() {
  var toggleParent = $(toggle).parent();
  if(!toggleParent.hasClass('persist'))
   toggleParent.removeClass('open');
 }

 $(function () {
  $('html').off('click.dropdown.data-api');
  $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus);
 });
})(window.jQuery);`

Comment: Turns out this was WAY easier to fix. See original